# TYPO3 persistAll() not working with AJAX call

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I want to update a database record like this:

```php
$persistenceManager = $this->objectManager->get("TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\PersistenceManager");
$person->setStatus(1);
$this->personRepository->update($person);
$persistenceManager->persistAll();
```

When I add a redirect everything works as expected. But when I call the controller as an AJAX request it's not updating the record.

I read on this [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/3-BlogExample/11-Alternative-route-creating-a-new-posting.html) that i just need to add

```php
$persistenceManager->persistAll();
```

after my update. But it's still not working.

I want to find out why it's not updating.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that all objects are correctly instantiate through an Ajax call, may be you can try something like this :

```php
    $objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);

    $person->setStatus(1);

    $personRepository = $objectManager->get(PersonRepository::class);
    $personRepository->update($person);

    $persistenceManager = $objectManager->get(PersistenceManager::class);
    $persistenceManager->persistAll();
```